# Is there a way to format JavaScript object and function parameters differently in IntelliJ?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'm just starting to dive into Node.JS, and by extension JavaScript, and am having a heck of a time reading code when a parameter could be an object or function.  I'm currently using IntelliJ's IDEA as my IDE, so is there a way in IDEA to independently edit the color/font for object parameters and function parameters?

**EDIT: Added Example**

I'm working my way through The Node Beginner Book by Manuael Kiessling (http://www.nodebeginner.org), so these examples are directly from there.

In index.js there is an object variable `handle` that serves as an associative array of url paths to function names, such that `handle` and `pathname` become objects.

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandler");

var handle = {};
handle['/'] = requestHandlers.start;
handle['/start'] = requestHandlers.start;
handle['/upload'] = requestHandlers.upload;

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

In router.js there is a function `route` that serves to direct handles that have a valid pathname to their respective function and invalid pathnames to an informative 404.

```
function route(handle, pathname, response) {
    console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
        handle[pathname](response);
    } else {
        console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        respones.write("404 Not Found");
        response.end();
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

In server.js there is a function `start` that uses `handle` (ala object) and `route` (ala function) as parameters to start the server.
var http = require('http');
    var url = require('url');

```
function start(route, handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log('Request for ' + pathname + ' received.')

        route(handle, pathname, response)
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log('Server has started.');
}

exports.start = start;
```

So, for the `start` function it would be nice to have some visual distinction between the `route` parameter, which is itself a function, and the `handle`, which is simply an object.

Comment: What do you mean by "object parameters"? Can you post an example of what you want to color?

Answer (score 0):

All JS functions *are* objects, so I don't think this is possible.

Comment: By that definition, aren't strings and integers also 'objects'?  Obviously strings and integers are objects of specific types, but so are functions.  If I print `typeof()` for a function to the console, it is identified as `function`.  Likewise, from my example, if I print `typeof()` for `handle` it is returned as a generic `object`.

Comment: IntelliJ (and every other IDE I've ever dealt with) provides a visual distinction between a string and a number by default, so why shouldn't it also be able to provide a distinction between a parameter that is a function and a parameter that is a generic object (or string, number, or what not)?  I've never seen an IDE that implemented a visual distinction to the parameter list, but most IDEs know what type of object a given parameter is, so why couldn't they be given different visual characteristics?

Comment: I'm not a professional coder, so maybe I'm missing some critical distinction.  But as a learner, such visualization would be really helpful.

Comment: For example, adding:

  `handleType = typeof(handle);
 functionType = typeof(route);

 console.log("handle is: " + handleType);
 console.log("this function is: " + functionType)`

between `function start(route, handle) {` and `function onRequest(request, response) {` results in:

    `handle is: object
    this function is: function`

Comment: Empish: Actually, IntelliJ doesn't distinguish between different types of parameters, it only distinguishes by their usage.  You can try it yourself: write a function and give it five parameters.  They'll all be formatted the same.  Now take one of those parameters and in the body of the function add `.elements` to the end, and it'll treat it like a DOM object.

Comment: So I've been trying to wrap my head around your comment and it's implications, but I can't get .elements to work.  I believe the reason I can't get it to work is that it is specifically related to the DOM, which is in turn specifically related to HTML.  While my question initially used a browser viewable code, and thus had aspects of html, none of the code in question is directly related to HTML.  So I wrote up a javascript only example (in other words browser & html-free example).  That example is the next comment in this thread.

Comment: Example code:   var aString = "forty-two";   
var aNumber = 42;   
function aFunction() {/* empty function */;}   
   
function testFunctionParameters(aS, aN, aF) {   
 console.log(" ");   
 console.log(aS);   
 console.log(typeof aS);   
 console.log(aS.elements);   
 console.log(" ");   
 console.log(aN);   
 console.log(typeof aN);   
 console.log(aN.elements);   
 console.log(" ");   
 console.log(aF);   
 console.log(typeof aF);   
 console.log(aF.elements);   
 console.log(" ");   
}   
   
testFunctionParameters(aString, aNumber, aFunction);

Comment: But I'm still left wondering why - if the language itself recognizes an object's `typeof` correctly, and the IDE is able to understand the language, then why can't a function's parameters be highlighted according to their type?  To add to my confusion, as I was typing up my example, I realized that for the function call in IntelliJ's IDEA, by default, it DOES highlight the string and number parameters differently than the function parameter. So why can't it do the same for the function definition itself?